How to upgrade ABP 5.3 to ABP 8.1?
I am currently working with an ABP Framework project template version 5.3, utilizing .NET 6. Now, I aim to upgrade it to the latest ABP Framework template, version 8.1, while also migrating to .NET 8. My project follows a Layered architecture.
Additionally, my frontend is developed using Angular, with a version of "~13.1.1".
I would appreciate guidance on the steps required for this update process. Specifically, I am unsure whether there exists a direct update option to version 8.1 or if I should follow a sequential update path, such as moving from 5 to 6, then 6 to 7, and finally reaching 7.8 before updating to 8.1.
Could someone advise on the best approach for this scenario?

I know, it quite old, but still.

There is no way to directly upgrade 5.x to 8.x
I highly recommend avoiding using 8.x until at least v8.2, there are too many bugs in the 8.1 at the moment around angular (they did change a lot in v8)

Upgrade path is well documented in the docs:
https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Migration-Guides/Index
You must go step by step, from to 5 to 6, then to 7, then to 8 (if you still want)
Migration of the .net core is separated process, but usually a simple one if you don't have a lot of customizations, you must manually change all projects to use corresponding version of the core. Also, please note that some projected targeted to .Net Standard also should be re-targeted to support multiple target frameworks (you will get few bugs if will skip this). You can create new empty solution from the abp template to see diff.
I did same way already, and again, recommend to stay on v7, overwise you will need to do re-implemet a lot of things by yourself.
Related issues:
https://github.com/abpframework/abp/issues/19807
https://github.com/abpframework/abp/issues/19804
https://github.com/abpframework/abp/issues/19806
https://github.com/abpframework/abp/issues/19656
